# MIDI Files Division SMTPE

Tags: midi

My question is regarding the division chunk of the header when the last word of the division is of SMPTE format i.e. the value lies between 0x8000 and 0xFFFF.

Lets say the division value is 0xE728. So in this case, the 15th bit is 1, which means it is of SMPTE format. After we have concluded that it is SMPTE, do we need to get rid of the 1 at the 15th bit? Or do we simply store 0xE7 as the SMPTE format and 0x28 as the ticks per frame?

I am really confused and I was not able to understand the online formats either. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The [Standard MIDI Files 1.0 specification](https://www.midi.org/specifications-old/item/the-midi-1-0-specification) says:

> If bit 15 of `<division>` is a one, delta-times in a file correspond to subdivisions of a second, in a way consistent with SMPTE and MIDI time code. Bits 14 thru 8 contain one of the four values -24, -25, -29, or -30, corresponding to the four standard SMPTE and MIDI time code formats (-29 corresponds to 30 drop frame), and represents the number of frames per second. These negative numbers are stored in two's complement form.

It would be possible to mask bit 15 off. But in two's complement form, the most significant bit indicates a negative number, so you can simply interpret the entire byte (bits 15…8) as a signed 8-bit value (e.g., `signed char` in C), and it will have one of the four values.